# RAWINPUT structure in C#

Tags: c#, winapi

MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms645562(v=vs.85).aspx

my current c# structs Looks like:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct RawInput
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)]
    public RawInputHeader Header;

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(16)]
    public RawInputData Data;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct RawInputData
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public RawMouse Mouse;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public RawKeyboard Keyboard;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public RawHID HID;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RawHID
{
    public int Size;
    public int Count;
    public IntPtr Data;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RawInputHeader
{
    public RawInputDeviceType Type; 
    public int Size;    
    public IntPtr Device;   
    public IntPtr Param;    
    public static int RawInputHeaderSize = Marshal.SizeOf<RawInputHeader>();
}

public struct RawMouse
{
    public RawMouseState Flags;
    private short Buttons;
    public RawInputMouseState ButtonFlags;
    public short ButtonData;
    public int RawButtons;
    public int LastX;
    public int LastY;
    public int ExtraInformation;            
    public static readonly int Size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RawMouse));
}

public struct RawKeyboard
{
    public short MakeCode;
    public RawInputKeyboardFlags Flags;
    private readonly short Reserved;
    public VirtualKeys VirtualKey;
    public WindowMessage Message;
    public int ExtraInformation;            
    public static readonly int Size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RawKeyboard));
}

[DllImport("User32", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int GetRawInputData(
        IntPtr rawInput, RawInputDataType command,
        [Out] out RawInput data, [In, Out] ref int size, int sizeHeader);  

[DllImport("User32", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int GetRawInputData(
        IntPtr rawInput, RawInputDataType command, 
        IntPtr data, [In, Out] ref int size, int sizeHeader);
```

My first question is, is the layout ok for 32 and 64 bit?

Now I try to get the raw hid data with:

```
int size = 0;
Win32API.GetRawInputData(
    message.LParam, 
    Win32API.RawInputDataType.Header, 
    IntPtr.Zero, ref size, 
    Win32API.RawInputHeader.RawInputHeaderSize);


Win32API.RawInput ri;
Win32API.GetRawInputData(
    message.LParam, 
        Win32API.RawInputDataType.Input, 
        out ri, 
        ref size, 
        Win32API.RawInputHeader.RawInputHeaderSize);
```

Now I try to get the Byte Array with:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[ri.Data.HID.Count];
Marshal.Copy(ri.Data.HID.Data, bytes, 0, ri.Data.HID.Count);
```

The Debugger just steps over these two lines. I think the layout is wrong, but Im not sure. Count and size of the hid structure is always Zero.

Does anyone knows where the error is?

Thanks!

Comment: Never, *never*, **never** ignore the return value of a winapi function.  If you don't check for errors then you can't find a mistake.  Throw a Win32Exception when it fails.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've taken these declarations from pinvoke.net, but unfortunately that is not a reliable source. There are a lot of mistakes.

The `RawInput` stucture declaration is not correct. You should use sequential layout for that. Only use explicit layout for unions.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RawInput
{
    public RawInputHeader Header;
    public RawInputData Data;
}
```

The rules to follow with unions are:

- Declare a type for each union. Use explicit layout with field offset of 0 for each member. Make sure that you define all the members, and not just the ones that you think you need. If you omit a member, the union type may be the wrong size.
- Use sequential layout for the structs, and include the union types as members of those structs.

We cannot see the declaration of `RawInputHeader` so we don't know whether or not that is correct. Nor can we see `RawMouse` or `RawKeyboard`. So they may be wrong.

The declaration of `RawHID` is wrong. This is a variable length structure, the final member, `bRawData`, is an inline byte array. You declared that incorrectly as `IntPtr`. The C# marshaller cannot marshal that for you.

Because `RawHID` is of variable length, the containing structure is also of variable length. That means that you will need to allocate unmanaged memory for the `RawInput` structure, and pass it to `GetRawInputData` as an `IntPtr`. You can use `Marshal.PtrToStructure` to read out most of the fields, but it will take a little more work to read out `bRawData`.

Your code fails to perform error checking. You must check for errors as documented.

Comment: I´ve added the other structs to the Initial post.

Comment: You've got to fix all of the problems

Comment: I´ve got it working. I thought I get a pointer to the byte array in bRawData. I managed it with Marshal.PtrToStructure with the pointer of the rawinput structure + size of the header struct.